# strace: order of <unfinished ...> and <... resumed>

Tags: linux, strace

I'm writing a script that analyzes file access traced with `strace`.

The trace contains some calls which have been interrupted by another process. `strace` shows them with `<unfinished ...>` and `<... close resumed>` (in case of an interrupted `close` call) markers.

```
[pid 26817] 12:48:22.972737 close(449 <unfinished ...>
[pid 28708] 12:48:22.972797 fcntl(451, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid 26817] 12:48:22.972808 <... close resumed> ) = 0
```

The process and all its threads have been traced with

```
strace -f -tt -p <pid>
```

The man page is uncertain about when the call has been finished.

> If a system call is being executed and meanwhile another one is being called from a different thread/process then strace will try to preserve the order of those events and mark the ongoing call as being unfinished. When the call returns it will be marked as resumed.

While I'd assume that, natually the `resumed` marker will indicate that the call is now finished. I'd like to ask if it is so.

Can the above trace excerpt be reconstructed to

#### A

```
[pid 28708] 12:48:22.972797 fcntl(451, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid 26817] 12:48:22.972808 close(449) = 0
```

or should it be reconstructed to

#### B

```
[pid 26817] 12:48:22.972737 close(449) = 0 
[pid 28708] 12:48:22.972797 fcntl(451, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
```

The order is crucial here since there may be multiple calls between the `unfinished` and `resumed` and one of them might do something with the file that is about to be closed at the moment.

Comment: The trace is correct, your "reconstructions" are not.  If the calls didn't overlap, the trace would have looked like either A or B in the first place.

Comment: I don't claim that `strace` is wrong. ;) I'd like to know when the file with handle `449` is no longer open. My understanding is that the `close()` call has been _interrupted_ by the other call. If it's actually being in progress and another process is making another system call within those 71 msecs this might be completely different from the pure technical point of view, but in my case it's the same: the file will be closed when `strace` "sees" the `unfinished`. Doesn't it?

Comment: If the program is still using the file descriptor after calling `close()`, that's a bug.  If the process tries to open the file *again* before `close()` returns, that could also indicate a bug.  So both call and return are shown in the trace.

Comment: @try-catch-finally: have you managed to reconstruct those calls? I'm into something similar and realized that there might be nested calls of same 'type' (i.e. function name), and I don't know how to know which ones to re-connect..

Comment: @frans I don't remember details after almost 10yrs, sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The system call *begins* when `strace` writes the line `close(449 <unfinished ...>`, and *ends* when it outputs `<... close resumed>`.

The `close` is not interrupted by any other call or signal: the other call is executed by another process, while the kernel is closing your file descriptor.

There is no way to know which is the exact point when the file descriptor is closed; the only thing you know is that it is not closed until the syscall is executed, and that it is closed when the syscall finishes.

Comment: Keep in mind that "unfinished" does NOT mean "interrupted at the kernel level." Rather, it means that the close() system call of 28708 takes some time (about 71 usec) and during that period, a different process/thread started a new system call - 28708 starts a fcntl(). Since strace can't report the return value (or any modified structure "output" values) until such call completes, it splits the report into two parts: the call initiation with "unfinished" and the call completion with "resumed." This has strace output interleave system call reports, as noted.